# Alterar a cor do texto ao clicar em um botão

Tags: html, css

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<style>

.alterar{ 
   color:red;
   text-align: justify;
}
</style>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> texto qual quer </h1>

<input id="botao" type="button"  value="Mudar de cor "/>


</html>
```

Pessoal estou fazendo uma pagina html basico e preciso fazer que ao clicar em um botão o texto fique vermelho e justificado.

alguém pode ajudar ?

Comment: Cara coloque o que vc já tem de código ai. É para ser só com HTML e CSS ou pode usar script?

Comment: Coloquei, sim pode usar script

Answer (score 13):

Uma opção só com html e css é usando o seletor `~` com ele quando o `checkbox` estiver `checked` vc troca a cor to texto e muda o alinhamento.

Aqui vc pode ler mais sobre esse combinador de seletor adjacente `~` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator

***OBS***: Se vc quiser esconder o `checkbox` coloque no `ID` dele `display:none`, ai vc clica direto só no texto da `label`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
#muda:checked ~ .box {
    color: red;
    text-align: justify;
}
.box {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="muda">
<label for="muda">muda cor e justifica</label>
<div class="box">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Minima odio qui, dolore, doloremque deleniti labore iure sit nulla totam adipisci optio quo! Dolor, deserunt! Delectus assumenda eos dicta quasi dignissimos.
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado hugo, ajudou bastante!

Comment: @DiogoSerravalle Sem problemas meu caro, eu fico feliz em ter ajudado

Answer (score 5):

Boa noite Diogo, tem várias maneiras de fazer isso:
A mais simples imagino que seria criando uma função em javaScript que altere a cor do texto desse modo e chama-la no html:

```
...
<body>

<h1> texto qual quer </h1>
<input id="botao" type="button" value="Mudar de cor " onclick="mudarCor()"/>

<script>

    function mudarCor(){
        // referencia o primeiro 'h1' do layout html
        const texto = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];

        texto.style.color = 'blue';
        texto.style.textAlign = 'justify';
    }

</script>
</html>
```

É possível fazer isso sem alterar o html de sua página, apenas adicionando um listener (escutador) para o botao, em javascript. Desse modo:

```
<body>
<h1> texto qual quer </h1>

<input id="botao" type="button" value="Mudar de cor"/>

<script>
    // referencia o primeiro 'h1' do layout html
    const texto = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
    // referencia o botao
    const botao = document.getElementById('botao');

    // adicionar um listener de click no botao
    botao.addEventListener('click', function(){
        texto.style.color = 'blue';
        texto.style.textAlign = 'justify';
    })
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado Rafael ajudou bastante, se eu precisar criar um outro botão mas nesse outro  a formatação seja: identado 20px apenas na primeira linha , tamanho 130% e negrito como ficar no script ?

Answer (score 4):

Uma maneira de utilizar um botão e trocar o texto da div é utilizar o **pseudo-elemento `:target`** e colocar um elemento **`a`** dentro do botão e manipular a div pelo seu `id`:

```css
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
.box{
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.box:target {
    color: red;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<button><a href="#box">Mudar Cor</a></button>
<div class="box" id="box">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Minima odio qui, dolore, doloremque deleniti labore iure sit nulla totam adipisci optio quo! Dolor, deserunt! Delectus assumenda eos dicta quasi dignissimos.
</div>
```

> Esta maneira só funciona ao clicar uma vez, se desejar que ao clicar novamente o texto fique com estilo inicial, o mais recomendado é como o Hugo fez utilizando **checkbox**

Answer (score 4):

Pode usar o método `.classList.add('nome da classe')` que irá adicionar a classe `.alterar` ao elemento selecionado quando o botão for clicado. Pode colocar o código dentro de um atributo `onclick`:

```
onclick="document.querySelector('h1').classList.add('alterar')"
         ↑__________________________↑ ↑______________________↑
                      |                           |
            seleciona o elemento         adiciona a classe
```

Vale notar que o `document.querySelector('h1')` irá selecionar apenas o primeiro elemento `h1` que encontrar. Portanto, se você tiver mais de um `<h1>` na página, será necessário identificá-lo com um id específico para aquele elemento, inserindo um atributo `id`:

```
<h1 id="h1"> texto qual quer </h1>
    ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

E colocar a `id` do elemento do `document.querySelector` para que o click no botão seja direcionado somente àquele elemento:

```
<input id="botao" onclick="document.querySelector('#h1').classList.add('alterar')" type="button" value="Mudar de cor" />
                                                   ↑↑↑
```

**Exemplo:**

```css
.alterar{ 
   color: red;
   text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="h1"> texto qual quer </h1>
<input id="botao" onclick="document.querySelector('#h1').classList.add('alterar')" type="button" value="Mudar de cor" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Deve colocar um id no h1:

```
<h1 id="texto> texto  </h1>
```

Adicionar um onclick no botão

```
<input id="botao" type="button"  onclick="trocarCor()"value="Mudar de cor "/>
```

E no javascript:

```
var titulo = document.getElementById('texto')

function trocarCor() {

     titulo.style.color = 'red'

     titulo.style.textAlign = 'justify'

}
```

Comment: Obrigado lvr7, ajudou bastante!

Comment: lvr7 se for para deixar em negrito seria assim : texto.style.fontWeight = 'bold';  ??

Comment: Exato, pode usar as mesmas propriedades do css.